# My sqlquery to display most Viewed

Tags: mysql

```
| id   | courseID | courseType | 
+-----------+-------------+----+
|  1   |    0     |     2      |
|  2   |    2     |     2      |
|  3   |    0     |     0      |
|  4   |    10    |     4      |
|  5   |    2     |     2      |
|  6   |    0     |     0      |
|  7   |    0     |     0      |
|  8   |    5     |     2      |
|  9   |    5     |     2      |
|  10  |    5     |     2      |
+-----------+-------------+----+
```

I want to list out first All CourseID with CourseType as

```
| courseID | courseType | 
+-----------+-----------+
|  5       |    2       |
|  2       |    2       |
|  10      |    4       |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: If you're trying to get the amount of occurrences of the pair `courseId, courseType` then you must use a `group by`

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct top 3 courseID,courseType
from table
order by courseID,courseType desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct courseID, courseType
from your_table
where 0 not in (courseID, courseType)
order by courseID desc
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Please don't ask questions in other users answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `courseId, courseType` pair with the most occurrences and omitting any of them with a `0` you should run this query:

```
SELECT courseId, courseType FROM t
WHERE 0 NOT IN (courseId, courseType)
GROUP BY courseId, courseType
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```